# Find a general solution for this ODE $ y^{\prime \prime}+4 y=0 \quad $ with $ \quad 0 \leq x \leq \pi $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a general solution for this ODE $ y^{\prime\prime}+4 y=0 \quad $with$ \quad 0 \leq x \leq \pi $

I tried to solve this ODE with the approach $y(x)=e^{\lambda}$. To find $\lambda$ we need to solve $\lambda^2+4=0$ so $\lambda_1=2i$ and $\lambda_2=-2i$. So the general solution would be
$y(x)=c_1e^{2ix}+c_2e^{-2ix}$  but the following solution is correct $ y(x)=c_{1} \sin 2 x+c_{2} \cos 2 x \quad$ with $c_{1}, c_{2} \in \mathbb{R} $
Can someone explain me how to get there?

Comment: Notice that $e^{2ix}$ is a complex number, and I suppose you want real valued solitions. Also notice that $e^{2ix}=cos(2x)+i sin(2x)$. If you have a complex valued function that satisfies a real linear ODE, then the real and complex part of the function also satisfies the ODE, and thats what happens here.

Comment: Your solution is nonreal = comlex, but the equation is real. So take the real and imaginary part and build a linearcombination. That's the general solution of this equation.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you for your help

Comment: @Fakemistake I have another question because I am unsure right now. Is the square root of -4 2i or 2i and -2i?

Comment: @Invader When talking about the square root as a function, we consider the positive branch. However, here what you are solving is the algebraic equation $\lambda^2+4=0$. The solutions are $\lambda=\pm 2i$, regardless of what the square root means.

Comment: @KBS Thank you very much.

Comment: The general approach is: The fundamental system for this differential equation is $\lbrace e^{2ix}, e^{-2ix}\rbrace$. Then show that $\lbrace \sin(2x),\cos(2x)\rbrace$ is also a fundamental system for this equation. But that's easy, since $\cos(2x)=(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})/2$ and $\sin(2x)=(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})/2i$

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I understood it.

Comment: Notice that $\sin(-2x)=-\sin (2x)$, and $\cos(-2x)= \cos (2x)$. Thus the trig terms from the two exponentials can be combined in pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you obtained is $$y(x)=c_0e^{2ix}+c_1e^{-2ix}.$$ Remember that $$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta),$$ so $$y(x)=c_0[\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)]+c_1[\cos(2x)-i\sin(2x)]=(c_0+c_1)\cos(2x)+i(c_0-c_1)\sin(2x).$$ You can simply let $C_0=c_0+c_1$ and $C_1=i(c_0-c_1),$ hence $$y(x)=C_0\cos(2x)+C_1\sin(2x).$$